# One more reason to reject an edit: too much alteration

Tags: discussion, feature-request, etiquette, editing, suggested-edits

I encountered this now, and have seen it quite frequently before: I would like to reject an edit, and the reason is something between "attempt to reply" and "clearly conflicts with author's intent". Usually (as in this case too) one cannot say there is no improvement, to the contrary, there is, sort of, too much improvement - to the point that it is almost a different question, maybe even better and more sensible; still, it is not clear whether the authors of the original questions would find it conflicting with their intent or not. All the same, I would prefer to reject the edit, and the reason I would name is that the edit introduces too radical changes.

I realize that I could explain myself in a comment after choosing "causes harm"; the problem is that I cannot also say it really causes harm, it is just that I find the edit too intrusive.

Also, since according to my experience the situations described are relatively frequent, and also in view of similar questions raised before, like [Editing etiquette](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2208/41291) or [Discreet editing](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1958/41291), maybe it makes sense to add a corresponding reason to reject, although I am not sure which formulation to choose: something close to "too intrusive" but the latter I find sort of vague.

What do you think?

Comment: There should perhaps be a way to let the original poster review the edit, instead of leaving this to random reviewers.

Comment: @darijgrinberg In fact, the OP has always the final decision. As mentioned in [this faq post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251): "The owner of a post or a moderator may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post." In fact, if reviewers have already approved/rejected suggested edit, the OP can still change this decision: [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178340)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I believe your comment qualifies as an acceptable answer. At least most likely I would accept it if no other answers would oppose it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, the OP can always reverse an edit. But it would help to provide a means of submitting edits for the OP’s approval without making them public first.

Comment: @MattF. If I understand your comment correctly, it is along the lines of this feature request: [Allow users who suggest an edit to choose that only the OP can approve/reject the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215975). (Currently at score $-12$.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, you understand me correctly — and I think that proposal would get a higher score here at MathOverflow Meta.